# Only 1 .SOL contract file is compiled in truffle project

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am having a very annoying problem but hopefully very simple to solve! I have a truffle project. In my contracts directory I have 2 files:

```
>     1_Migrations.sol
>     2_Factoring.SOL
```

When I type compile --all from the command line, the compiler only compiles 1_Migrations.sol. I deleted all the .JSONs to see what would happen and the result is nothing happens - no compile and no JSONs created apart from Migrations.JSON.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a simple problem to solve! The problem was the two SOL files were named slightly differently and it came down to case sensitivity:

> 1_Migrations.sol and 2_Factoring.SOL

I simply renamed 2_Factoring.**SOL** to be 2_Factoring.**sol** and low and behold the compiler did what I expect it to do! I hope that this will help someone else struggling with this problem.